NamedPipeClientStream and System.UnauthorizedAccessException
I'm trying to use named pipes to let a Windows service and an application share messages.
SERVICE
var ps = new PipeSecurity();
//ps.SetAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule("Everyone",
    PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));
//ps.SetAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(
//    new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null),
//    PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite,
//    AccessControlType.Allow));
//ps.SetAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(
//    new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinUsersSid, null),
//    PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite,
//    AccessControlType.Allow));
ps.SetAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(
    new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null),
    PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite,
    AccessControlType.Allow));

var serverPipe = new NamedPipeServerStream(NamedPipeHelper.PipeName, 
    PipeDirection.InOut, 1, 
    PipeTransmissionMode.Message);
serverPipe.SetAccessControl(ps);
await serverPipe.WaitForConnectionAsync(ct);

APPLICATION
var clientPipe = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", NamedPipeHelper.PipeName, 
    PipeDirection.InOut);    
await clientPipe.ConnectAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), ct);

As soon as application tries to connect to service, I get

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied

As you can see I set server security and also tried several different solutions, but nothing worked.
I've also tried to run the service as a simple application (running elevated), but when client connects from an unprivileged account I get the error.
If a run the app with a privileged user, connection works (both with service and the server running as a simple app).
Several blogs and websites are saying solution is to pass security within the ctor, but with net8 this is not possible.
I'm stuck, don't know how to solve this.

After a lot of reaserch I dig into this post and found David Steinberg's answer: that's the only working solution!
var serverPipe =
    NamedPipeServerStreamAcl.Create(NamedPipeHelper.PipeName, 
    PipeDirection.InOut, 10, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, 
    PipeOptions.Asynchronous, default, default, ps);

I hope this is not the intended behaviour of namedserverpipe and that it will be fixed in the future, 'cause it is absolutely not straigthforward to understand how you should use it.
Why can't we use the regular ctor?

As noted in that post, it's because creating a new stream needs special permissions, if you don't have them then it won't work. NamedPipeServerStreamAcl.Create calls an internal constructor with the specific permissions for just opening, it's not clear why it's not a public constructor. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.IO.Pipes/src/System/IO/Pipes/NamedPipeServerStreamAcl.cs

My post has been closed as duplicate, but the other one was targeting a different .net and had a different accepted solution, that does not work for this scenario. Anyway I also wonder why MS hid that ctor, I think it's not wise, that's all

See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31095#issuecomment-540773661 as referenced from https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31112 "We considered adding the APIs back to the relevant types (i.e. as constructors). While this would be preferred from a porting/backwards compabitility case, it would mean we'd have to pull-in a large amount of ACL / Windows security into System.Private.Corelib. We think these APIs are weird and shouldn't be exposed"
